# validation of email FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL is not working but my error is not nbot solved function is not working

Tags: php, html, css

```
<?php 
function validateUser($user)
{

    $errors = array();

    if (empty($user['username'])) {
        array_push($errors, 'Username is required');
    }

    if (empty($user['email']) && !filter_var($user['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        array_push($errors, 'Email is required');
    }

    // if (!filter_var(($user, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) {
    //  array_push($errors, 'Email is required');
    // }

    if (empty($user['password'])) {
        array_push($errors, 'Password is required');
    }
    // if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
 //      $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
 //    }

    if ($user['passwordconf'] !== $user['password']) {
        array_push($errors, 'password do not match');
    }

    $existingUser = selectOne('users', ['email' => $user['email']]);
    if ($existingUser) {

        if (isset($user['update-user']) && $existingUser['id'] != $user['id']) {
            array_push($errors, 'Email alraedy exists');
        }
        
        if (isset($user['create-admin'])) {
            array_push($errors, 'Email alraedy exists');
        }
    }
    return $errors;
}
```

Comment: every thing is working validation of email is not working

Comment: You need to give us some examples of what "not working" means. We can't read you rmind and as far as I know, that function works just as expected.

Comment: Also try and dump an example of troublesome input.  `var_dump($user);`

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
if (empty($user['email']) && !filter_var($user['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    array_push($errors, 'Email is required');
}
```

on this

```
if (empty($user['email']) || (!empty($user['email']) && !filter_var($user['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))) {
    array_push($errors, 'Email is required');
}
```

Comment: not working @ramiz kong it have same functioning that above statement have wrong email is exceptable but i wnat to validate

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for either an empty email or an invalid one in one if:

```
<?php
if (empty($user['email']) || !filter_var($user['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    array_push($errors, 'Email is required or invalid.');
}
```